# Magento 2 - Contact us page returns 404 even though enabled in configuration

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I have enabled the 'Contact us' page in the Magento 2 configuration and I have created a 'contact-us-info' static block (although I don't think this is necessary) but I have no contact us page on the front end.

I have run php 'bin/magento setup:upgrade' and cleared the cache but I can't see why this doesn't work. I am using a theme I have built based on [Studioemma Optimus](https://www.studioemma.com/) theme (which is based on Magento Blank)

Is it possible that I just have the wrong URL suffix?

I'm using /contact-us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `<website_url>/contact` in general. Try that one.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. Thanks so much, that is about the only iteration I didn't try but I couldn't find it documented anywhere.